# css - relative DIV has no height

Tags: html, css, css-position

I do not understand whats wrong with my code. I mean, section element has the height, display value of my DIV element is definitly block and i really dont know how it works and how to combine these two elements differently positioned. Please give me your solutions and advices to learn something new today.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30%;
}

div section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

hr {
  height: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section></section>
</div>

<hr>
```

Comment: what is your final result?

Comment: What exactly is the problem and what do you want to see as a result?

Comment: i need height for my div element

Comment: then use height: ~px on div

Comment: Well, the `div` will not grow with its content in your case, as the `section` has position absolute

Comment: [why](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgZKQO)?

Comment: @Olga You ask me why?

Comment: div's height will be independent of children with position: absolute, it'll increase only if the children with position relative has some height.

Comment: yea i knew that i tought its possible @anurag

Comment: An absolute positioned element is taken out of flow, and will behave, kind of, that it does not exist at all for the surrounding elements, hence the div in this case will have height 0

Comment: I've got your point @LGSon I've thought that the problem was just a height of the div

Comment: @felixsturm Now you know why, is this how you wanted it to be? https://jsfiddle.net/wrdsofdh/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want your hr on the bottom of the first div, right ?

However, this is not working because the parent div have an default `height: auto` property.
This mean that the parent div will have the height of his children.
When you set a `position: absolute` on a child, you are breaking this system.
The parent will no longer take care of his child.

So, if you want to make it works, you have **two** **solutions**:
 - set a custom height (`height: 100px`) on the parent div *(not good)*
 - remove the absolute position on the child section (default :`position: relative`)

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30%;
}

div section {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

hr {
  height: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section></section>
</div>

<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your element has height set to AUTO. If you want to change your div height you need to write this in css.

```
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think This is because your `div` has no height itself that's why it is not visible and it is increasing according to its child element which is   `section`  and is in `absoulute` position. I am not sure what you are up to but If you want to show the section inside the div along with the div's height the you must include the css for your div .

I provided an assumption solution for you hope it helps you

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
}
section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
div hr {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <p>your div</p>
    <hr>
    <section>your section</section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```